# Will IIS stop this thread?

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, iis

Hello I am make a long running service class that runs diffidently but it's thread is paused all the time except for once a day when it has to check some data for my asp.net website. It is a WCF file in an asp.net website. The class inherits from this interface :

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    void DoWork();
}.
```

This is the code it uses for creating the thread the class run on :

```
//Initialize the thread
Thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(threadDoSomething));
//The thread is a background thread; it is a long running service
Thread.IsBackground = true;
//This Thread does not need much CPU attention so it is not a high priority
Thread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Lowest;
//Run the tread
Thread.Start(this);
```

I have heard that IIS will occasionally stop long running processes to save memory, will it stop this process?

Comment: Well, which is it? A Windows Service or an ASP.NET app? That looks more like a WCF contract than a windows service.

Comment: Given that you're checking something once per day, wouldn't it make more sense to create this as a Console application, then use a Scheduled Task to fire it off at the correct time?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, IIS will recycle ApplicationPools when no activity has been received in a period (it's configurable).

A simple trick to avoid this is to do that thread navigate a page on your web application to avoid it but it will finally sometime recycle it after a long period.

**UPDATE:**

Ehm... if your app is a windows service then IIS has nothing to do with your thread...

Comment: It is a in WCF file on a asp.net website? Will asp.net stop that?

Comment: Yes, it will stop, that's not a windows service, it's a web service.